# How to read and display data in cakephp while using query function i.e. from custom query?

Tags: cakephp

I used following format for custom query:

```
$data = $this->Login->query("select * from logins;");
```

How do I read and display data from the `$data` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
```

//Updated code

```
$this->set('data',$data);
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Chetan....The above code u gave returns an array but I wanted to know how this array I can dispay to front end as read() function do...If I write $this->Login->id=$id;
  $this->set('login_array', $this->Login->read(null, $id)); and then in CTP file I use <?php echo $login_array['Login']['first_name']; ?>.....so tell me how that array that i got from Custom query be displayed??

Comment: in ur controller,                                                  $data = $this->Login->query("select * from logins;");              $this->set('data',$data);

Comment: Instead of `print_r` just use `pr();` or `debug()`